# Using shortcodes in php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use shortcodes in my php template in wordpress and using the following code does not work. Please help:

```
<?php
 $args = array('post_type' => 'package', 'package-category' => 'South Africa',     'posts_per_page' => 6);
 $loop = new WP_Query($args);
 while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

$thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail();

$mc_content = <<<MCC
<div class="four columns gdl-package-grid2">
    <div class="package-content-wrapper">
        $thumbnail
    </div>
</div>
MCC;


echo do_shortcode('[tab_item title="ITEM_TITLE"]' .$mc_content. '[/tab_item]');



endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: I think that you're not doing anything wrong, but that for some reason that shortcode just won't let you inject HTML tags into it. It will work fine with plain text, however.

Comment: yes it works fine with plain text. Anyway other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

This may be help.

```
echo do_shortcode('[tab_item title="ITEM_TITLE"]' .addslashes($mc_content). '[/tab_item]');
```